# Force `input` change in shiny after shinyjs::reset

Tags: r, shiny

I'm working on an app and have run into an issue. Here's the repex:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'shinyjs'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:shiny':
#> 
#>     runExample
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:methods':
#> 
#>     removeClass, show

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  selectInput("working", "Working", choices = c("Select" = "", "Yes", "No")),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.working == 'Yes'",
    uiOutput("dynamicOccupationQuestion")
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$dynamicOccupationQuestion <- renderUI({
    req(input$working)
    if (input$working == "Yes") {
        selectInput(
          "occupation",
          "What is your current occupation?",
          choices = c("Write down your occupation" = "", "Manager"),
          selectize = TRUE,
          width = "100%"
      )
    }
  })

  observe({
    if (input$working == "No") {
      print("Resetted input")
      reset("occupation")
    }

    print("Current occupation")
    print(input$occupation)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If I run the app, click on 'Yes' for 'Working', pick an occupation and then click on 'No' in occupation again, the print statement I introduced on the server side shows the occupation I picked, even when I set an observe statement reactively resetting `input$occupation` if `input$working` was set to 'No".

The current print statements return this:

```
[1] "Current occupation"
NULL
[1] "Current occupation"
NULL
[1] "Current occupation"
[1] ""
[1] "Current occupation"
[1] "Manager"
[1] "Resetted input"
[1] "Current occupation"
[1] "Manager"
```

With the last occupation being 'Manager' despite me resetting it with `reset`. I was expecting something like this:

```
[1] "Current occupation"
NULL
[1] "Current occupation"
NULL
[1] "Current occupation"
[1] ""
[1] "Current occupation"
[1] "Manager"
[1] "Resetted input"
[1] "Current occupation"
[1] ""
```

With the last occupation being "". If I instead click on 'Yes' for 'Working' again I get the occupation resetted but I'm specifically looking to reset the occupation without having to show/unshow the question again. Any ideas would be very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working.  You can see it in the next observer.  Try this

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$dynamicOccupationQuestion <- renderUI({
    req(input$working)
    #if (input$working == "Yes") {
      selectInput(
        "occupation",
        "What is your current occupation?",
        choices = c("Write down your occupation" = "", "Manager"),
        selectize = TRUE,
        width = "100%"
      )
    #}
  })

  observeEvent(input$working,{
    if (input$working == "No") {
      print("Resetted input")
      reset("occupation")
    }
  })

  observe({
    print("Current occupation")
    print(input$occupation)
  })
}
```

Comment: If I run your exact code the final line is `[1] "Resetted input"` and don't see any occupation being printed.

Comment: The more I think about this, isn't this simply the fact that `reset` changes the input but doesn't do it 'reactively', meaning that not all other `input$occupation` get triggered as if had changed?

Comment: Change the selection to "Yes" again.

Comment: Yep, thanks, that as a mistake from my side. Thanks!